# Check whether posts are deleted before allowing flags from the review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, flags, moderator-tools

I have run into this situation a few times where the following is happening.

- I see a flag on a post, normally an AutoVLQ on an old post.
- I delete the post
- A little later, I get another flag on the same post, this time from a user

In all cases, I can look at the timeline for the post and see that the second flag was raised after I deleted the post.  I have seen the second flag as much as twenty minutes after I deleted the post.

As far as I can tell, the flags are coming from posts in the review queue.

To be honest, I think this is either a bug in the review queue with deleted posts not being removed, or a caching issue, but I am framing this as a feature request.

**The Request**

> When a flag actually gets added to a post (ie, in the postback
>   handler), check whether the post has been deleted.  If the post has
>   been deleted, then add it to the flag queue only if it has a custom
>   reason or is a spam/offensive flag.  If it not, then automagically
>   dismiss it as helpful.

This should cover the legitimate reasons for a moderator to see a flag on a deleted post.

Comment: If a post has been deleted, the only possible flag is a custom one. The flag dialog looks at the state the post is in at the moment the dialog is loaded.