# Users under 10k flagging posts that were deleted by review several weeks before

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, deleted-answers, review-audits

I just reviewed a custom flag on an answer that basically said it was not an answer. This answer had been deleted by review on April 29. The flag was raised *today*.

This is the second time I've had to deal with a flag that was raised on an answer weeks after it had been deleted by review. The first time was probably a day or two ago, and it was from a different user on a different post. I'm guessing the user didn't have 10k reputation either, but I'm not certain. I don't have the link to the first post anymore and I'm lazy to scour my browser history for it. [Here's the post that was flagged today though.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357448/how-to-read-an-external-sharepoint-list-using-c/23359439#23359439) And a screenshot for the curious — you can clearly see it was deleted weeks ago:

[image]

Anyway, I declined the flag — because why in the world would you flag a post *weeks after* it had been deleted and forgotten?! — and then I found out that the user who flagged didn't even have 10k rep. So that makes this even weirder, because how was the user even able to see the post in order to flag it then (other than the stupidly unlikely possibility that they might have kept their browser open with that same answer for three whole weeks without refreshing or turning off their computer)?

In any case, if two separate users have managed to do this in two separate instances, then something is very wrong.

Comment: Related or dup http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231684/check-whether-posts-are-deleted-before-allowing-flags-from-the-review-queue

Comment: That user *did* receive the post [as a review audit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4839769). Although I'm not sure why it allowed them to submit the flag. It should have instantly completed when they clicked the flag button.

Comment: @m0sa: Has this issue regressed? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456096/woocommerce-shop-page-products-link-to-external-directly/24277925#24277925 Flagged more than 30 minutes after deleted from review.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425697/apple-push-notification-new-protocol-not-working/29414547#29414547 Flagged 14 hours after being deleted from review.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed rolled out with build rev `2014.5.20.1616`.

There was a problem with the initialization of the voting and flagging dialog in the  review queues. The `StackExchange.vote_closingAndFlagging.init` call memoizes the first options ever passed to it, and discards all options from subsequent init calls. We missed this *little detail* when implementing [this community request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168824/using-the-flag-loophole-to-pass-every-review-audit/231658#231658), and the review queue was stuck in either *normal review* or *audit* mode between page reloads.

Comment: Oopsie. :-) So, just out of curiosity, what happened if you tried to flag a real post while it was stuck in audit mode?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Probably something like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231892/226203)

Comment: @BillyMailman indeed, the close vote wouldn't be / wasn't recorded, only the review result was.