# List of users in the "on hold" banner different from those who reviewed as "close"

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, closed-questions

I was reviewing the close vote queue. While there, I voted to close a question. Meanwhile, I opened that same question, there I saw that the names who voted to close it are different than those in the close vote review.

Below are the examples :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743004/c-sharp-how-to-use-progressbar-to-indicate-file-compression-process
against this close vote review https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4849763

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743071/working-with-several-models-edit-list-of-users-related-brands against this close vote review https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4849843

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23742753/why-cant-i-install-my-service-on-my-server-using-wix against this close vote review https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4849669

I noticed this on Stack Overflow, but this might apply to other sites too.

Comment: Looks okay to me, except 'rene' reviewing to close and not being on the list. Might be retracting their votes after the fact? Ultimately, a person can easily vote outside the queue, and also change their vote after the fact, so there's no actual reason the two lists should line up perfectly.

Comment: No, I **NEVER** retract my votes! There is a reason why I'm in top close vote reviewers list... :-)

Comment: Then there's definitely something weird going on. Maybe review something and immediately go to it outside the review queue to see if the votes aren't taking properly?

Comment: @rene just plain isn't showing up in the timeline that there was *ever* a close vote. Same goes for Jay in the first link.

Comment: @animuson Is that caused by me? Or by IE11? (Yes, I still use that browser)

Comment: If you're showing in the Review list, the server knew on some level that you said you wanted it closed, so it's pretty likely a problem on SE's end. Gonna need one of the devs in here to look at it, though.

Comment: @rene it's always you. Maybe you ran out of close votes?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nope, I was handling my 40 tasks and after that I had still close votes left...you only see me because I provided the OP with the samples...

Comment: @rene so it's weird. Need a dev!

Comment: It was probably actually being caused by [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231921/226203), now that I've seen that. If Rene was hitting an audit as their first review, it'd have gotten stuck not actually sending the votes through.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described [(and fixed) here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231829/156631) the issue was that the close dialog could be initialized with the review audit settings, and failed to update those between task reloads. As a consequence only the review result (w/o/ the close flag) was recorded.